# 403 on new apache2 installation

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, http-status-code-403, apache2

I had lampp installed previously. I uninstalled it using sudo ./uninstall
But even after i uninstalled it, it was showing me the contents of /opt/lampp/htdocs.
I used sudo rm to remove the directory too.
Then I installed apcache using

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server php php-mysql libapache2-mod-php php-xml php-mbstring
```

But now it says

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

How can I fix this?
Is there some other application running on :80 rather than any of the apache installations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest to

```
apt-get purge apache2
```

And after that, remove the /etc/apache2 directory completely for clean any custom config.

Now with apache "cleaned" reinstall it again using:

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Also you can monitor what process are listening on port 80 with this command:

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 80
```

Comment: depending on the previous installation it might be possible that the uninstall script did not stop the old lampp apache process resulting in it still running.